# Windows workflow not waking up after delay

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We have windows workflow service with two Sequences. between these two sequences there is delay activity set to  `new TimeSpan(0,0,10)` that is 10 seconds.

```
MainSequence
   Sequqnce_1
   Delay
   Sequqnce_2
```

So after 1st sequence executed WF persist to SQL server and then after 10 sec it wakes up to do 2nd sequence.

This was working for last 3 years. But suddenly (since yesterday) WF stops after waking up after delay

I enabled `system.diagnistics` in web.config and in the log i see the following

> DisplayName: 'Sequence_1', InstanceId: '2' has completed in the
>   'Closed' state
>
> Activity 'System.Activities.Statements.Sequence', DisplayName:
>   'MainSequence', InstanceId: '1' scheduled child Activity
>   'System.Activities.Statements.Delay', DisplayName: 'Delay'

After that there is nothing in the log.

When i check Workflow database i see the entry in 
`[System.Activities.DurableInstancing].InstancesTable` however i noticed `PendingTimer` is NULL

I am not sure if `PendingTimer` NULL is causing this issue, and if it is why WF is setting it as null?

**UPDATE 1**
Turned out my coworker ran windows update on that server which installed .Net 4.7 on the server. However WF application is set to target framework 4.5.1.
I am not sure if the update is causing this issue

**Update 2**

I enabled ETW tracing to see whats going on and i see the following exception

**The version of the database cannot be determined as no rows were found in System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable. This table should contain a single row that corresponds to the version of the framework that it was created with or upgraded to**

Complete exception

> System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089The version of
>   the database cannot be determined as no rows were found in
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable.
>   This table should contain a single row that corresponds to the version
>   of the framework that it was created with or upgraded
>   to. at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.PersistenceTask.CommandCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The version of the database cannot be determined as no rows were found
>   in
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable.
>   This table should contain a single row that corresponds to the version
>   of the framework that it was created with or upgraded to. at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Activities.DurableInstancing.PersistenceTask.CommandCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

When i check `System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable`, its empty. However this table was always been empty. This issue is happening on `Development` server ( where we ran windows update that installed .NET 4.7)

We also have other environments `Staging` and `Production`, *where windows updates are not installed yet*. I checked `SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable` on these server and indeed the table is empty however Workflow is running fine without any issue on these servers

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go through this link for migration of your .net framework

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.6.2-4.7

Comment: Thanks this really helped understanding what has changed. Basically my application's target framework is 4.5.1. We have been installing new dot net framework on the server. There is no updates in Window Workflow Foundation till 4.6.2 so everything was working. However with 4.7 there is change in Windows Workflow. Anyway to solve my issue i just added a row in SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreVersionTable

Comment: on sidenote where would i get WWF's SQL script for .NET 4.5.1

Comment: You can find the WF SQL persistence scripts here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SQL\en

Comment: More info on running those scripts here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-enable-sql-persistence-for-workflows-and-workflow-services